# Find sample standard deviation with mean and mean of their square

Tags: standard-deviation

I have a problem to find sample standard deviation when only the mean and mean of their square are given. 
Mean = 19.19 and mean of their square is 618.10

How to calculate sd when there is no N value given here?

Comment: Welcome to MSE!  What have you tried so far?  Where are you stuck? https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Comment: @Dzoooks That's what the question is about? I have no clue from where should I  start?